Dropdown menu overlaps with component in Vue app
I had a Vue electron app, in which Home view component has 3 child components which are in single column one after the other, I have a b-dropdown in middle component when I scroll up the opened dropdown it's hidden under the top first component, How to handle this case?
I need to show the b-dropdown on top of the component not under the components.

HomeView.vue :--
  <div>
      <div v-if="!is_loading && show_service_list" class="home_view_wrap">
        <ServiceList @alertservicelist = "showSessionAlert" />
      </div>
      <div v-else-if="!is_loading && show_information_list" class="home_view_wrap" :key="componentkey">
        <InformationList @alertinfolist = "showSessionAlert" />
      </div>
      <div v-else-if="!is_loading && show_device_list" class="home_view_wrap">
        <DeviceList />
          </div>
      
    </div>

informationlist.vue component code :
<div class="information_list">
    <div class="card text-left" :class="(!show_service_list && !show_device_list && show_information_list) ? 'information_list_card_border' : ''">
      <div class="card-header information_list_header bg-light">
        <label id="id_lbl_link_service_list" class="pb-0 mb-0">{{ $t('notification') }}</label>
        <div class="" v-if="show_dropdrown">
          <b-dropdown id="dropdown-1" variant="outline-info" :text="langConvert" style="color: #17a2b8;" >
            <b-dropdown-item

              v-for="option in options"
              :key="option.value"
              :value="option.value"
              :class="option.value === information_type ? 'dropdown-item-active' : ''"
              >
              {{ option.text }}
            </b-dropdown-item>
          </b-dropdown>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>


You need to share code that you have used to make this work, without having the code its not possible to share a solution.

Updated the code please check , Thank you

Share the HTML output! Not some vue component code that cannot be reproduced. Read [ask] and how to provide a [mcve].
